# Unity: UNetWeaver warning: SyncVar set from within property function. This will not set dirty flags. How to?

Tags: c#, unity

I was trying out the new Unity networking and I added the `SyncVar` attribute to one of my variables to be synced. I also have a property to get/set the variable and update the visuals when set. I set the "hook" variable in the SyncVar so the property is used and visuals are updated properly (or that was the idea, since it gives an error :P)

```
[SyncVar(hook = "set_Tapped")]
private bool _tapped;
public bool Tapped
{
    get { return _tapped; }
    set { _tapped = value; UpdateRotation(); }
}
```

Now however I get an error in the console:

```
UNetWeaver warning: SyncVar [_tapped] set from within property function [System.Void Card::set_Tapped(System.Boolean)]. This will not set dirty flags.
```

How should this be handled? I could just make a `set` method myself (not using properties), but is there a better/nicer way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

Given [this unnecessarily complex post](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/29/unet-syncvar/) and [this possibly useful but awfully long manual page](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetStateSync.html), it's safe to say that just rewriting it to be a normal function instead of a setter, would be order**s** of magnitude easier than any other solution.

---

That being said, here's an alternative approach, that uses `SyncVar`:

```
[SyncVar] private Status status = Status.Free;
private Status prevStatus = Status.Free;

void Update ()
{
    if (status != prevStatus)
    {
        DoStuff();
        prevStatus = status;
    }
}
```

Over `Rpc`, this has the advantage of being "automatically" synced to new clients, at the expense of being slightly less obvious/readable/clear.